# Custom Push Notification - Full width background color

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-push-notification, android-remoteview

I am implementing custom push notifications. I have a custom layout, modified using RemoteViews. I have set color using

```
        contentView.setInt(R.id.parentLayout, "setBackgroundColor", Color.parseColor("#4979C5"))

        notifBuilder.setColor(Color.parseColor("#4979C5"))
       .setColorized(true)
```

But it doesn't set color completely on background. I want it to have like this Android system notification

[image]

but I am getting this

[image]

Here is the styling that I have used:

```
notifBuilder.setColorized(true)
                .setColor(Color.parseColor("#4979C5"))
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setContent(closedView)
                .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_tick)
```

I have tried using other styles and also removed the style but I get this result

[image]

Which seems to be fine as it does have background color set on complete notification area but now there is no details like app name, notification time, app icon and expand icon. Even action buttons are gone.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: @KrutikaChotara You can't use NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle() for full width notifications. Solution was to not set any style on notificationBuilder and add app icon, app name & notification time by yourself in your custom view.

Comment: I got your point to remove the style and add app icon & name in custom view. But how you managed expand/collapsed button ?

Comment: unfortunately, there was no solution for that. notification will be either expanded or collapsed

Comment: this will not work in Android 12 if target version is 31.

Comment: for android 12 & above, there will be no full width notifications. According to documentation